# Hide field based on value of select box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.1 and I am rendering a form. I have an additional field that I only want to be shown if the user selects 'Other' in the select field. I currently have it showing the additional field once other is selected, however if the user saves their choice on page reload it does not load the additional field again even though the select box is other.

`Here is the jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_gender_custom').hide();
    $("#user_gender").change(function() {
        if ($("#user_gender").val() == "custom") $("#user_gender_custom").show();
        else $("#user_gender_custom").hide();
    });
});
```

If I remove the initial `$('#user_gender_custom').hide();` it does always loads the additional field on a page load even if the select box value is not Other.

Can anyone show me how to get this working correctly? Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: please try `$("#user_gender option:selected").val()=="custom"`

Comment: @Pekka I tried that within the if statement and it does not show the additional field on page load if the value is set to `custom`.

Comment: you should call on the change manually. please add $("#user_gender").change(); after change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only problem is the initial load (the field is always shown), maybe it makes sense to do something like that:

```
function toggle_custom() {
  if ($("#user_gender").val()=="custom")
    $("#user_gender_custom").show();
  else
    $("#user_gender_custom").hide();
}

$(function() { 
  toggle_custom();
  $("#user_gender").change(function() {
    toggle_custom();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that @the-ancient but on page load the default value of the check box is `select one` and the additional field shows even though the value is not `custom`

Comment: This could be as it looks like the syntax is incorrect I am seeing this in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @DMH - I've edited the code to fix that; there was a missing `)` in the penultimate line.

Comment: Having tested this it works great thanks @the-acient

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_gender").val("custom")
    $('#user_gender_custom').hide();
    
    $("#user_gender").change(function() {
        if ($("#user_gender option:selected").val() == "custom") $("#user_gender_custom").show();
        else $("#user_gender_custom").hide();
    });
  $("#user_gender").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='user_gender'>
  <option val=''></option>
  <option val=''>custom11</option>
<option val='custom'>custom</option>

</select>
<input type='text' id='user_gender_custom'/>
```

Please add on change manually. So that the change function will be call on load

Comment: The only issue with this is say you come to fill in the form for the first time the default value is set to custom when it should be the prompt to select one.

Comment: And say you actually have it set to male then it will always set to custom when someone goes to edit it.

Comment: no you dont need to manually set the value i just show you that if there is value in select the change event should be called so the important thing is on load you should call the change event where the value of select is changed or not the input will be hide or show depending on the value of select

Comment: Dont set it manually what is important here is you call the event change on load so that the hide and show will be called depending on select value

Comment: i just set it manually so you can see that on load it will show the input if the select value is custom

Comment: Ah sorry @Pekka I had not realised. I shall take a look at the solution. Thank you for your help.